# Constructing a sequence that is pointwise bounded but not uniformly bounded by points in a closed, nowhere dense set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I believe that this question below is asking for a sequence of functions that are bounded pointwise in $\mathbb{R}$ but NOT uniformly bounded in a closed, nowhere dense set of $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $J$ is a closed and nowhere dense set in $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to construct a sequence of non-negative functions $f_n$ which are continuous for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and where we have a constant $M_x$ such that $f_n(x) \leq M_x$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, BUT where for every $x \in J$ and for any open interval $I$ that contains $x$, we have that the sequence $\sup_{I} f_n$ is not bounded.

So far what I have done is to first define the set of functions as:

$$f_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{n} & \text{if} \space \space \space x \in J \\
            \frac{1}{d(x)} & \space \space \space x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus J\space \space \space  \text{where $d(x)$ is the distance from $x$ to $J$}
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

I am not sure if the above would actually work. I would like to construct a sequence where the limit will be:

$$f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \text{if} \space \space \space x \in J \\
            \frac{1}{d(x)} & \space \space \space x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus J\space \space \space  \text{where $d(x)$ is the distance from $x$ to $J$}
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

I feel I am on the right track but am not completely sure as the function seems a bit weird. Would anyone have any insight if my sequence $f_n(x)$ actually works? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea for your function $f$ seems good. Let $d(x)$ denote the distance of a $x\in \mathbb{R}$ to $J$. To define $

For every $n$, define $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{d(x)}&\text{, if }d(x)\geq 1/n\\
n^2d(x),&\text{, if }d(x)\leq 1/n
\end{cases}$$

Notice that $f_n$ is well-defined and continuous. Each $f_n$ is bounded by $n$ and for every $x$, the sequence $(f_n(x))$ is constant from some $n_0$ on, so $f_n(x)\leq n_0$ for every $n$. Notice that $f_n\to f$ pointwise.

Now, let $x\in J$ and $I$ and open interval containing $x$. Since $J$ is nowhere dense, we can find a sequence $y_n\to x$ in $I$, $y_n\not\in J$. Notice that, in particular, $1/d(y_n)\to \infty$. For every $n$, choose $M_n>1/d(y_n)$, so that $f_{M_n}(y_n)=\dfrac{1}{d(y_n)}$. This shows that the sequence $(\sup_I f_{M_n})$ is not bounded, so $(\sup_I f_n)$ is not bounded as well.

Comment: When you said that "Notice that, in particular, $\frac{1}{d(y_n)} \to 0$", did you mean $\frac{1}{d(y_n)} \to \infty$ instead? Thanks!

Comment: @user123276 Yes. Thank you. Already corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

For an open interval $(a,b)$ define a function $u_n^{a,b} :\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} ,$ $$u_n^{a,b} (t) =\begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ for } x\leq a \\ n \mbox{ for } a<x<a+\frac{b-a}{2n} \\ 0 \mbox{ for } a+\frac{b-a}{2n} \leq x\leq b-\frac{b-a}{2n} \\ n  \mbox{ for } b-\frac{b-a}{2n} <x<b \\ 0 \mbox{ for } b\leq x \end{cases}$$
Since $J$ is closed then $\mathbb{R}\setminus J =\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} (a_j , b_j )$ where the intervals are pairwise disjoint.
Let us define $$f_n (t) =\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} u_n^{a_j ,b_j} (t) .$$
I think that such defined sequence $(f_n)$ should be good.